# Некорректно работает функция, возвращающая Фамилию и Имя

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

```
std::string changePlayerName () {

    std::string playerName;
    std::getline (std::cin, playerName);

    // для ввода доступны русские и английские символы, ровно один пробел, дефис (пример: Михаил Салтыков-Щедрин)

    const std::regex nameProperties ("^[А-Яа-яA-Za-z'’-]{2,64}\\s[А-Яа-яA-Za-z'’-]{2,64}$"); // почему-то не работает

    while (std::regex_match(playerName, nameProperties) != 1) {
        std::cout
                << "\nНеверный формат. ФИ хоккеиста должно содержать два слова, написанных на русском или английском языке."
                   "\nМожет включать в себя дефис(-) и апостроф('|’)"
                   "\nПопроуйте снова... ";
        std::getline(std::cin, playerName);
    }
    std::cout << "Имя " << playerName << " принято!" << std::endl;
    return playerName;
}
```

Функция работает некорректно, пропускает строки типа "asdasasd", а "Алексей Иванов" - заворачивает. Что я делаю не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выражение я, вроде, верно написал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 3):

У Вас проблема с кодировкой. Сохраните файл в кодировке Windows-1251 и отредактируйте функцию changePlayerName.

```
std::wstring changePlayerName() {

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    std::wstring playerName;
    std::getline(std::wcin, playerName);

    const std::wregex nameProperties(L"^[А-Яа-яA-Za-z'’-]{2,64}\\s[А-Яа-яA-Za-z'’-]{2,64}$");

    while (std::regex_match(playerName, nameProperties) != 1) {
        std::wcout << "\nНеверный формат. ФИ хоккеиста должно содержать два слова, написанных на русском или английском языке."
            "\nМожет включать в себя дефис(-) и апостроф('|’)"
            "\nПопроуйте снова... ";
        std::getline(std::wcin, playerName);
    }
    std::wcout << "Имя " << playerName << " принято!" << std::endl;
    return playerName;
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Благодарен вам за ответ! Возможно, вы знаете как решить эту ситуацию под Mac OS 10.15.2 ?) В любом случае, повышаю.

Comment: @acc попробуйте без вызовов SetConsole и сохраните файл в кодировке Кириллическая Windows